# Can I give an employee more that one warning a day?

Tags: discipline

I would like to know if I can give one particular employee 3 warnings on a day.

She is a rep at my company and does merchandising is stores. After I went thru the reports and photos of the 3 stores she visited in one day, there was discrepancies of in the stock counts.
The issue of discrepancies and not counting all the stock has been address with her previously. Her excuse is just, I'm Sorry, will count everything next time"

So I want to know can I give her 3 warnings for the 3 stores that was not done correctly on one day, or only one warning as it is the same offence committed on one day in 3 different stores?

Comment: What exactly constitutes "a warning"? That is, if it's a legal/formal thing, what country are you in, what impact will the warning have etc.

Comment: Maybe you should assign 10.875 warnings (since the discrepancy differs between each store, you must take into account the average discrepancy over all affected stores, and then apply a weight to the warning value of each store proportional to the expected profit for that store on the affected day). After all, if she receives an appropriately weighted warning this will probably better motivate her to improve her performance.

Comment: Follow your company's discliplinary process, this should be documented.  If not, it needs to be and your employees all need to be aware of it.

Comment: Are you asking if you can give the hypothetical  "three warnings' needed before someone is fired all on the same day? Try editing the question to reflect that.

Comment: My personal opinion is that if you are doing this so you can fire the person, it is rather an unfair thing to do even if HR will allow. Give one warning, let her know that future instances will lead to getting fired and that you will be checking and give her some training on how to do the task correctly. Now if the failure is something she has been warned about or if there are other performance issues she was warned about or if the behavior puts the business at risk, the advice might be different. But if this is the first major mistake she is aware of, give her a chance to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter how you do it as long as the end result is that she is aware that she is miscounting at every store.

Given that the issue of miscounting the stock is systematic, is the issue an undercount or can the miscounting be either undercount or overcount? Systematic undercount means she is missing some areas of the store. Random undercount/overcount suggests carelessness.

Systematic undercount can be addressed by having her go over with you where she did the counting. Random overcounting/undercounting should be addressed by admonishing her to check her counting. Saying that she miscounted without digging into how she miscounted shows inadequate supervision. And since she does not know any better, she is going to make the same promises that she no doubt will break again. You, as a supervisor, need to work with her to resolve the issue. Otherwise, you are not doing your job.